# Based on Bayes' theorem calculate mixed probability

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

let us consider following picture
[image]

I really  did not understand how he calculated

P(review us |spam), I am working on paper to clarify example,that why I draw  tree diagram , for simplicity let us  focus on first example, here is my tree diagram

[image]

so on the base of this tree diagram , how to calculate mixed probability ? please help me, the way he wrote formula is a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna address the picture you quoted and not the tree diagram on the whiteboard.

There are six words ordered as seen in the table on the right: {`password`, `review`, `send`, `us`, `your`, `account`}.

If a word is in the sentence under examination, then it's a $1$, otherwise it's a $0$. This way we can encode the sentence as a string of binaries of $0$s and $1$s.

So we have a new email with the sentence "review us now". The last word "now" is ignored because it is not in the dictionary.

- The word `password` is not in it so it's a $0$.
- The word `review` is in so it's a $1$.
- `send` is not in so $0$.
- `us` is in so $1$
- `your` is not in so $0$
- `account` is not in so $0$.

This becomes $P(\text{review us}~|~\text{spam} ) = P(\{0,1,0,1,0,0\}~|~\text{spam} )$

For ones we have $p_i$ and for the zeros we calculate as $1 - p_i$, where $p_i$ is the corresponding conditional probability listed in the "spam" column in the same table: $$\{p_1,\, p_2,\, p_3,\, p_4,\, p_5,\, p_6\} = \{ \frac24, \, \frac14, \, \frac34, \, \frac34, \, \frac34, \, \frac14\}~.$$

The first word **in the dictionary** (first row) `password` is not in the sentence (encoded as $0$), and it has a conditional $p_1 = \frac24$. The contribution of this word to the likelihood is $1 - p_1 = (1 - \frac24)$

The second word in the dictionary (second row) `review` is in (thus encoded as $1$) and has a conditional $p_2 = \frac14$. Its contribution to the likelihood is $p_2 = (\frac14)$ where the parentheses are just to indicate the contributions from different words.

The third word in the dictionary ($3$rd row) `send` is NOT in, encoded as $0$, with a conditional $p_3 = \frac34$, and its contribution to the likelihood is $1 - p_3 = (1 - \frac34)$

So on and so forth.

The same procedure goes for $P(\text{review us}~|~\text{ham} ) = P(\{0,1,0,1,0,0\}~|~\text{ham} )$, with the same encoding (same dictionary) but calculated using the conditional probabilities of the other column (given that it is ham): $\{ \frac12, \, \frac22, \, \frac12, \, \frac12, \, \frac12, \, \frac02 \}$

Comment: and we should multiply  all probabilities?

Comment: this multiplication i did not understand

Comment: From this one slide shown (either a lecture of a colloquium), I can only speculate. This is perhaps the calculation of [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Continuous_distribution,_continuous_parameter_space), just like the MLE (maximum likelihood estimator) that leads to least square method in ordinary linear regression etc.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aZNAmWKGfs